# When one of my column in dataframe is nested list, how should i transform it to multi-dimensional np.array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have the following data frame.

```
test = {
    "a": [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,2],[3,4]]],
    "b": [[[1,2],[3,6]],[[1,2],[3,4]]]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(test)
df
```

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [[1,2],[3,4]] | [[1,2],[3,6]] |
| 1 | [[1,2],[3,4]] | [[1,2],[3,4]] |

For example, I want to transform the first column to a numpy array with shape (2,2,2). If I use the following code, i will get a array with shape (2,) instead of (2,2,2)

```
df['a'].apply(np.asarray).values
```

How can I get the array with shape (2,2,2)?

Answer (score 1):

The following code works:

```
np.array(list(df['a']))
```

Comment: `np.array(df['a'].tolist())`. 25% faster :)

Comment: There should be even a faster solution using [`np.fromiter`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) with nondefault `count` option. But it is a little bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

When creating dataframes that contain lists or arrays in the columns, it's a good idea to have a clear sense what's stored.

```
In [545]: df
Out[545]: 
                  a                 b
0  [[1, 2], [3, 4]]  [[1, 2], [3, 6]]
1  [[1, 2], [3, 4]]  [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

A frame is a 2d object, one column, a Series, is 1d.

`to_numpy` returns an array (`np.array(df)` and `df.values` do the same):

```
In [546]: df.to_numpy()
Out[546]: 
array([[list([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), list([[1, 2], [3, 6]])],
       [list([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), list([[1, 2], [3, 4]])]], dtype=object)
```

It's 2d, but object dtype means it contains (references) lists.  `df.info()` also tells us that.

```
In [547]: df['a'].to_numpy()
Out[547]: array([list([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), list([[1, 2], [3, 4]])], dtype=object)
```

to_numpy of a column is 1d, again object dtype.

```
In [548]: df['a'].to_list()
Out[548]: [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]]]
```

This is a pure (nested) lists.  As with a hand written nested list, it can be turned into an array with:

```
In [550]: np.array(df['a'].to_list())
Out[550]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]])
```

For the array version you need to use `stack` to combine them:

```
In [551]: np.stack(df['a'].to_numpy())
Out[551]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]])
```

A different concatenation method:

```
In [552]: np.vstack(df['a'].to_numpy())
Out[552]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Comment: Excuse me, what's the point of this too long and mixed with "In [5xx]" and "Out [5xx"]" answer? *"it's a good idea to have a clear sense what's stored"* They are lists as shared in the question, what's to clarify? *"you need to use stack"* Then why is there `vstack`? Copy-paste left over?

Comment: @Neither, I routinely copy-n-paste examples from a `ipython` session.  This one just happens to have been in use for several days.  A dataframe stores its values in a 2d numpy array (or several depending on the mix of dtypes).  Admittedly an object dtype array is very list-like.